# Update Maven dependencies in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, repository

I'm new to the ​​intellij idea.

I'm trying to add a dependency (for example) jcl-over-slf4: jar but it is not added, here is an error in the logs.

```
017-12-02 14: 40: 41,903 [6473161] INFO - # org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: some problems occurred while processing POM:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.groupId' for: jcl-over-slf4: jar is missing. @line 31, column 16
```

I close the Idea and deleted everything in .IntelliJIdea14\system\Maven\Indices and cleared the whole .m2\repository directory

Restarted the Idea and in the settings I'm trying to connect to the central maven repository,  but first time it loads slowly. Now it does not load at all
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoq5v.png)

I turned on auto-import and turned off the firewall and antivirus. Allowed access to the Internet. Set VM  options `-Xmx1024m` But the problem remainded.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYphI.png)
But the size of the .m2 / repository folder is only 27 megabytes (and you need 270).

The idea of ​​version 14.1.6.

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring-test-app Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4</artifactId>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>spring-test-app</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

What else should I do to load all the dependencies?

Comment: Seems rather a Maven configuration issue than an issue with Idea. Most likely at line 31 of your pom.xml you did not specify a groupId (which should be `org.slf4j`). Please attach your pom.xml.

Comment: I edited topic message and attached pom. but in intelej the error label "jcl-over-slf4 <unknown>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a version to your dependency, like

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It works, but I would like that, there were drop-down lists with available dependences.

Comment: @Sergu There should be intellisense in Idea by pressing ctrl+space in pom.xml.